# how to generate a new variable with loops

Tags: loops, stata

I'd like to generate a dummy that contains certain characteristics.

```
mgr firm enterdate leavedate newdummy
A    x      1        3          .
B    x      3        5          1
C    x      6        15         1
D    x      8        15         0
E    x      9        15         0
```

If all managers enter before this manager have a leavedate smaller than the current enterdate, the dummy equals one.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please insert your example data as (formatted) text, bot as image.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. Just changed to text but I think it may be harder to read than it is in the picture...Sorry that I don't know how to make the text better...

Comment: I don't understand the last sentence, so I won't try to edit it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you please let me know how to input the example in this nice way so that I can do it like this next time. Thanks again! @RalfStubner

Comment: @MengqiaoDu See here https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is what is desired, or at least a start in the right direction.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. To install: ssc install dataex
clear
input str1(mgr firm) byte(enterdate leavedate newdummy)
"A" "x" 1  3 .
"B" "x" 3  5 1
"C" "x" 6 15 1
"D" "x" 8 15 0
"E" "x" 9 15 0
end
generate maxlv = .
bysort firm (enterdate): replace maxlv = max(leavedate[_n-1],maxlv[_n-1]) if _n>1
generate nd = .
replace nd = maxlv <= enterdate if maxlv!=.
list, clean
```

which yields

```
       mgr   firm   enterd~e   leaved~e   newdummy   maxlv   nd  
  1.     A      x          1          3          .       .    .  
  2.     B      x          3          5          1       3    1  
  3.     C      x          6         15          1       5    1  
  4.     D      x          8         15          0      15    0  
  5.     E      x          9         15          0      15    0
```